# In Postgresql, how can I fetch an unknown # of records from a table that have M distinct values in one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose a table named tau.

```
tau:
A | B | C
----------    
2 - 1 - 12351
3 - 1 - 65462
4 - 1 - 13461
6 - 5 - 12351
7 - 5 - 12351
8 - 5 - 62372
9 - 10 -12351
```

Column A is the primary key. It will be unique. Column B is a foreign key. In my database no integer key is ever the same across tables. Column C is not a key.

This table will have a lot of rows. There are many other columns, say column C for instance, that are indexed for search.

I want exactly M distinct values from column B. Lets say M = 2

Normally, I would go

```
select distinct B From tau Where C = 12351 Order By B Desc Limit 2
```

and I get

```
B
-----
10
5
```

This is the current state of affairs, now. But I want to upgrade to a new scenario:

When a value in column C adds the record to the results pile (where C = 12351), I want to return column A as well as column B, **while maintaining the restriction of 2 at most distinct column B values.**

Behold, the results I want.

```
A | B
------
9 - 10
7 - 5
6 - 5
```

The trouble is, the actual limit of records returned can be greater than M, or 2 in the example. I don't really care how many records come through, as long as there are only M distinct values of B. How would I write a query to accomplish this in Postgresql?

Comment: You need to decide if your query should return one column or two.  If you have a variable number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I want two columns. I need to associate A with B when the C expression adds the result to the pile. I've edited the question to clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close to what you want by doing something like this:

```
select A, B
from tau t
where (B, C) in (select distinct B, C
                 From tau
                 Where C = 12351
                 Order By B Desc
                 Limit 2
                );
```

This always returns column A, but otherwise seems to be what you want.

Comment: Getting column B is sufficient, but getting the tuple A - B would be a lot better.

Comment: Since `C = 12351` you do not need to select it in the sub-query, nor filter on it in the main query.

Comment: @Patrick . . . I would have to add the condition `C = 12351` to the outer query.  I prefer to mention such constants only once, if feasible.

Comment: I used a bad example. I should have stipulated that the query must work for any condition on column C. There are possible conditions that return true for C values that aren't necessarily the same. In this case the inner query might skip some results.

Comment: @IsaacBolinger . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with a better description of what you are trying to do and data closer to your actual problem.  If you edit this question, you might invalidate this answer, which would draw downvotes.

Comment: You are right. I'll post again. The second version is definitely a lot harder.